# Como definir quantidade de box com flex

Tags: css, css3

Se eu utilizar `display:flex` em uma estrutura `ul>li`, todos os itens ficarão espremidos em uma única linha. Gostaria de saber se é possível determinar o limite por linha, como três por exemplo..

Sei fazer com `float:left`, mas gostaria de usar `flexbox`..

> Ex: Determinar que irão aparecer três LI por linha

```
<ul>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A pergunta é interessante. Se sabe fazer com float:left, com flexbox é parecido. Você pode definir uma largura minima em cada bloco pra que caibam só 3 na linha. Agora, uma curiosidade: Qual a vantagem de usar flex-box se vai ter quantidade fixa de ítens por linha? Outro cuidado: se, por um acaso, for fazer algo com função de tabela (apresentar dados naturalmente tabulados), o elemento correto é `<table>`. (Mas é engraçado, tem gente que não entende que o `table`, desde que usado corretamente, ou seja, para tabelas, é um elemento tão válido como qualquer outro).

Comment: Ainda nao tenho certeza se irei usar flex ou float, mas quando fui desenvolver, veio-me as duas ideias, e entao surgiu a duvida.. Acredito que seria um opção, algo a mais, sabe? Teria um exemplo em cima do html da pergunta?

Comment: Acredito que `li {min-width:30%}` já resolva. O bom do flex em relação ao float é você fazer com que o preenchimento da linha seja 100%, o que com float é mais chatinho por causa do arredondamento das porcentagens. Se puser o CSS atual no seu exemplo fica mais fácil de alguém dar uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Acredito que seja apenas isso, foi apenas uma ideia que me surgiu! 
De qualquer forma, e mais uma vez, obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode definir uma largura nos flex-items, para eles ocuparem a o espaço total (100%), metade(50%), 1/3(33%), etc...

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
/* 1 por linha */
/* width: 100%; */

/* 2 por linha */ 
/* width: 50%; */ 

/* 3 por linha */
/* width: 33%; */

/* 4 por linha */
  width: 25%; 
}
```

obs: Não esqueça de adicionar a propriedade flex-wrap: wrap; no elemento pai, para que ela permita a quebra de linha dos flex-items.